# What does mean "Last Interaction" in User Usage parameter description

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-apis-explorer, google-admin-sdk

I need to know what does mean `timestamp_last_interaction` in User Usage Reports (API Admin SDK) gmail parameter description. The documentation doesn't have too much information about it and i would like to know what exactly is counted to this parameter because my reports do not represent the what a think they should do.

Comment: Could you maybe share a link page where you find this parameter? What do you exactly want to achieve? Maybe there is another way to actually make it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/user/gmail - this is the parameter link, the description is just "Last interactive access timestamp", but I would like to know what which classifies access as interactive access, if that interactive access could be just an email opening event for example.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing and checking up. I can confirm you that everything you do counts towards this parameter.

Taking any action or even log in gmail would actually update this parameter.